# how can we export data in excel sheet date show in different column

Tags: php, mysql

How can we export data in Excel sheet date show in different column

**Code :**

```
error_reporting(0);
ini_set('display_errors',0);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
include('include/function.php');
include('include/report_header.php');

$user=new User();

session_start();

$sql= "SELECT enginner_name,in_time,out_time FROM `enginner_timesheet`  ";          
$results = mysql_query($sql);



$sql=$_SESSION["sql"];

$fdate=$_SESSION["fdate"];

$todate=$_SESSION["todate"];


$begin =  new DateTime($fdate. " 00:00:00");
$end = new DateTime($todate. " 23:59:59");

$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day');
$period = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end);
$count=0;
$new1='';

foreach ( $period  as $dt ) {
    $new=$dt->format("Y-m-d");
    $new1.=" ' ".$new." ' , ";
}

$new1=substr($new1, 0, -1);
//echo $new1;

date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; 
filename=pikaObs_'.date("Ymd").'.csv');

$handle = fopen('php://output', 'w');

fputcsv($handle, array('Engineer_Name','in_time','out_time',$new1));

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($results)) {

    fputcsv($handle, array($row['enginner_name'],$row['in_time'],$row['out_time']))
}

fclose($handle);
```

Comment: I want data in excel format like name 1 to 30 date show in a row

Comment: whats' the error when you run your code?

Comment: error not showing but data not in formatted pattern i want all engineer attandance sheet in excel sheet but date column show all month date  in single column i want date  like 1 to 30 in different column

Comment: Show the screen of your expected output .

Comment: col1   col2   col3    col4 ...............coln

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since in-time and out-time are within a single day, It's better to use one column. So I combine the two columns using concat().

```
 //Here we grab date from and to from form
$fdate=$_SESSION["fdate"];//suppose it is in yyyy-mm-dd format
$todate=$_SESSION["todate"];

$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'root', 'pass');
$q = $db->query("SELECT id, enginner_name,  `date` as datework, 
                 concat(in_time, '-', out_time) as timespent
                 FROM `enginner_timesheet` 
                 WHERE `date` BETWEEN '$fdate' AND '$todate' 
                 GROUP BY enginner_name, `date`");
$sub=array();
$eng=array();
while($row=$q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $sub[$row['id']][$row['datework']] = $row['timespent'];
    $eng[$row['id']]= $row['enginner_name'];
}
$subkey=key($sub);
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="yourexcel.xls"');
header('Pragma: no-cache');
header('Expires: 0');

echo '<table>';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<th>Engineer name</th>';
foreach($sub[$subkey] as $keys=>$vals){ 
        echo '<th>'.formatDate($keys).'</th>';//date column
}
echo '</tr>';
foreach($sub as $key=>$val){
       echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>'.$eng[$key].'</td>';//engineer name
        foreach($val as $v){
            echo '<td>'.$v.'</td>';//time loop
        }
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
function formatDate($d){
   $date = new DateTime($d);    
   return $date->format('d/D');
}
?>
```

You are using old depracated mysql extension. In this answer I use PDO because I feel it is better for you. You can even use prepared statement which is more secure. As phpfiddle does not support concat() function I could not put online demo. Just test and see. I have tested in my local machine and it is working fine.
Note: mysql extension is depracated. Use PDO or myqli.

Comment: Warning: fputcsv() expects parameter 2 to be array null given in C:\wamp on this line  fputcsv($csvoutput, $headers);      
          fputcsv($csvoutput, $row);         I am new in php and its a important work for me anything missing mr  MAWIA HL

Comment: Add your sql data in the question so that I can work on it later.

Comment: yes exactly but i have made changes in date function how can i send sql file to you

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `enginner_timesheet` (
  `id` bigint(30) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `enginner_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `zone` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `designation` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `in_time` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `out_time` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `company_name` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `other_details` varchar(600) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=17903 ;

Comment: INSERT INTO `enginner_timesheet` (`id`, `date`, `enginner_name`, `zone`, `designation`, `in_time`, `out_time`, `company_name`, `other_details`) VALUES
(61, '2015-02-18', 'Abdul', '', '', '10:15', '', '1)algyas-cuffparade,2)', ''),
(62, '2015-02-18', 'Afsar ', '', '', '10:08', '', '1)priyanka-goregaon,2)pallav-andheri-W,3)marnavi ship-andheri-W,4)', ''),
(63, '2015-02-18', 'Ahmed', '', '', '10:15', '', '1)emrald-nariman point,2)align-fort,3)dave & co-fort,4)', '');

Comment: Create your expected output in image and I will give the solution.

Comment: upload in some free image hosting site and share the link here.

Comment: Tahnks Mawia pls check i am sending o/p screen where only one date record come and i select whole month date  http://e72i.imgup.net/screen4d9c.jpg

Comment: hello mawia r u check above link

Comment: The problem is you need to include `date` in your group by. So the new group by statement would be `SELECT id, enginner_name,  `date` as datework, concat(in_time, '-', out_time) as timespent
                       FROM `enginner_timesheet` 
                       WHERE `date` BETWEEN '2015-02-18' AND '2015-02-28' 
                       GROUP BY enginner_name, `date`

Comment: You can click the tick icon above to accept as answer.

Comment: $sub[$row['enginner_name']][$row['datework']] = $row['timespent'];
$eng[$row['enginner_name']]= $row['enginner_name'];   use this code for replce id to engineer name and than give me a correct ans thanks mawia dear

Comment: So, what's your problem?

Comment: @Mukesh patidar, It's a waste of time if you don't click the tick icon when my answer did help you solve your question. If this answer helps, you should click the tick icon above.